# How to use await/async with ssh-exec?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to run command with ssh and I am getting value not sure how to use await and async here so that I can close thread once it saves data into DB

```
require('dotenv').config()

const db = require('../lib/db');
const exec = require('ssh-exec')

var getModems = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  var v_host = '122.12.19.160'
  exec('proxysmart-remote.sh list_online_modems', {
    user: 'root',
    host: v_host
  }).pipe(process.stdout , function (err, data) {
    resolve(data);
  })
});


const saveModems = function () {
  getModems.then(function(value) {
    // save into db
    console.log(value);
  });
}

saveModems()
process.exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don´t need to use promises, ssh-exec returns a stream, you can bind functions to some stream events like:

```
let acc = '' // This is the variable where we accumulate every chunk of the stream.
exec('something')
  .on('data', function(chunk) {
    acc = acc + chunk
  })
  .on('close', function() {
    db.save(acc) // or do whatever you need.
    db.close() // Here we close the database connection how is supposed to be done.
  })
  .pipe(process.stdout)
```